# Is there any way to install windows features like IIS just using command line interface?

Tags: iis, command-line-interface, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, webdeploy-3.5

I would like to provision a windows server 2012 with:

- Web Server
- Web Deploy

and other IIS features.

When I look at articles describing how to install there is a lot of images to show me what to do, just using a **GUI** way, but, command line interface is safer and faster than "click > next > next > finish many times"...

So... There is a way to use just **command line** to install these features on Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

Try [installing IIS from the command line](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-from-the-command-line), it is for 2008, but I assume it applies for 2012 or at least a better alternative was developed.

If you plan to use this for provisioning machines on which you will deploy Web Deploy Packages, another method is to create an MSI package to deploy both the Web Deploy Package and also enable the windows features. For example, with Advanced Installer you can use the [built-in support for Web Deploy Packages](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/web-deploy.html).

Instead of writing a script to enable Windows Features, you can use the [built-in functionality for enabling Windows Features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgIzPcJeIGI#t=89) from Advanced Installer. This will configure the MSI to automatically enable those Windows Features, if they are not found enabled on the machines where your application(s) will be installed.